# Java: incompatible types, possible lossy conversion from double to float

Tags: java, floating-point

why do I get this error message when i try to compile the following code?

```
float a = 1/0.1;
System.out.println(a);
```

or

```
float b = 1/0.002;
System.out.println(b);
```

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float

Am i getting an overflow? I'm looking to understand the theory behind this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `0.1` and `0.002` are `double` literals. So you end up with `int/double` which results also in `double` value. Since you are trying to assigning that `double` value to `float` variable, there is a risk of reducing precision which is why compiler is warning you about.

Comment: By default Java evaluates `0.002` constant literal to `double`. You may want to have it like `float b = 1 / 0.002F;`

Answer (score 1):

Use float literals:

```
float a = 1f / 0.1f;
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.1` and `0.002` are `double` literals. Java’s `double` type has more precision than its `float` type. So, when you convert from `double` to `float`, the number may be changed by rounding it to the nearest value representable in `float`. Using decimal as an analogy, assigning the four-digit .1234 to a two-digit type would produce a different number, .12.

When you do this conversion implicitly, by assignment to a `float` variable, the compiler tells you there could be a loss of information. By using a cast, you tell the compiler the conversion to a less precise format is intentional. Or by using `float` literals such as `0.1f` and `0.002f`, you work with `float` values throughout and avoid conversion.

Generally, pick one type, `float` or `double` and use it throughout your calculations, for both literals and variables.